# How to Separate columns from a DataFrame into a new dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a DataFrame that consist of 15 columns in total of unique names. for simplicity, say my column names are column1, column2, column3 up to column15.

```
DataFrame:

Column1    Column2    Column3    .....    Column15
1          2          3                   4
1          2          3                   4
1          2          3                   4
```

So I wanted my output to be 15 separate new dataset consisting of 1 column only.
For example:

```
Dataset_1:

Column1
1
1
1
```

then another separate one

Dataset_2:

```
Column2
2
2
2
```

then another separate one

Dataset_3:

```
Column3
3
3
3
```

I'm pretty much new in programming so I don't know much about it. Please help me. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your dataframe to a dict of series like this:

```
dataset = df.to_dict(orient='series')
```

```
>>> dataset['Column4']
0    4
1    4
2    4
Name: Column4, dtype: int64
```

Note: I strongly discourages you to create X number of variables. So, avoid to do the code below:

```
for idx, col in enumerate(df, 1):
    locals()[f"dataset_{idx}"] = df[col]
```

```
>>> dataset_7
0    7
1    7
2    7
Name: Column7, dtype: int64

>>> dataset_12
0    12
1    12
2    12
Name: Column12, dtype: int64
```

Now you have 15 python variables.

Comment: 15 rows or 15 columns? You want one python variable for one column, that's right?

Comment: So I have an original DataFrame with 15 columns. And I want to separate each column to a new dataframe. So in total I will have 15 different Dataframes with 1 column each

Comment: OK. I strongly discourages you to do that but if you want, I updated my answer.